# Does Linux kernel support Trigonometric functions and floating point arithmetic?

Tags: linux-kernel, floating-point

I see from network that linux kernel doesnot support floating point arithmetic,but my module for kernel has many "double" variablities 、 floating point arithmetic and Trigonometric functions like "tan"、“sin” and "acos" . How should I do ?  All codes in kernel only use integer？

Comment: What have you tried ? have you seen this ? : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-perform-floating-point-operations-in-linux-kernel-873551/

Comment: I try the operation as follows:double i,j;
int result;
i=5.0;
j=2.5;
result=i/j;
printk("<0>result=%d\n",result);    and get result:2. This means the kernel can support floating point arithmetic?   But if result is defined as double, printk can putout nothing.  I see the url you give, but not very understand.

Comment: Compiler likely optimized this out. Try more interesting example where you might get even compilation error.